# Styling definition lists to conditionally break

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to style a definition list so that the description is on the same line as the term only if it fits.

Consider the following DL list:

```
<dl>
<dt>BeOS</dt>
<dd>Developed by Be Inc. in 1991. The open-source Haiku is a reimplentation of BeOS.</dd>
<dt>Apple ][e ProDOS</dt>
<dd>Marketed by Apple as "Professional Disk Operating System", and was the last OS used by Apple II computers.</dd>
<dt>z/OS</dt>
<dd>IBM's latest successor to the vernable MVS, for zSeries mainframes</dd>
<dt>Commodore AmigaOS</dt>
<dd>The native operating system for Amiga computers.
</dl>
```

Let's say we want the dd column to be indented 5em. The styled result should be:

```
BeOS        Developed by Be Inc. in 1991. The open-source Haiku is a 
            reimplentation of BeOS.

Apple ][e ProDOS
            Marketed by Apple as "Professional Disk Operating System", and
            was the last OS used by Apple II computers.

z/OS        IBM's latest successor to the vernable MVS, for zSeries
            mainframes.

Commodore AmigaOS
            The native operating system for Amiga computers.
```

The key is that when the term is longer than the dd margin, the dd block appears on the next line, like it would without special CSS. But if it does fit, then it *does* appear on the same line.

I've figured out how to get it to always break, and never break, but I can't see how to get it to conditionally break, and still maintain consistent indentation of the dd block.

**Update:** by request, some CSS... For the case of always inline, I came up with:

```
dt {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    min-width:calc(5em-1ch);
    margin-right:1ch;
}                  
dd {
    margin-left:5em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

This is different from other posted solutions because I wanted the dd to wrap around the term, but stay aligned regardless of the term length.

For the conditional break problem, the closest I can get is to have the dd as a block that floats:

```
dl {overflow:auto;}
dt {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
dd {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

But the problem is the indentation of the dd block. When it doesn't fit, it should be indented. But when it does fit, the margin causes the entire block to be indented too far.  Similar problems occur if I try to give it a relative position.

Comment: Can you show us your CSS?

Comment: CSS doesn't really *do* conditional breaking AFAIK. I think you may just have to pick one or the other.